# 2 Color CSS Icons

Tags: css, icons

Is there a way to make css icons like [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) (or any other CSS icons) have 2 colors?

I know they are fonts so the color can be changed by something like `style='color: red;'`, but is there a way to use 2 colors for the icons like an accent color and a main color?

Comment: use `color` & `backgroud-color`

Comment: Can you post an image of the desired effect?

Comment: Possibly using `fa-stack` - http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only options you have are,

1. You can use text-shadow to give it a different colored shadow or stroke.
2. You would need to use svg icons to control the path colors.

Comment: svg seems like a good idea, but I never used it before.  would you be able to show a working jsfiddle of svg usage with 2 colors? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `color` & `background-color` to control 2 color on the same icon, as long as you only need 2 colors (no other background).

`<i class="fa fa-motorcycle blue onred"></i>`

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
.onred {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv86neLm/)

Comment: That does not apply two colors to the **symbol**...that just colors the background.

Comment: @Paulie_D you're right, and I clearly stated that, but perhaps it's good enough for the OP.

Comment: If he wanted to color the background, don't you think he would have said so? He clearly wants two colors on the **font**.

Comment: A. I saw far more obvious questions asked. B. That's for him to judge, not you. C. It's good to know you're a mind reader

Comment: No, just basic English comprehension but perhaps you're right.